# gdb under msys2 on windows 11 can't use layout "not a terminal" is there a terminal under windows?

Tags: windows, gdb, msys2

using msys2, when I use gdb it does not allow the command:

```
layout asm
layout reg
```

because it says "cannot enable TUI when output is not a terminal"
The terminal is set to xterm which matched TERM. I found that the msys2 shell has a configuration for different types and tried VT525 and VT220 but somehow gdb says it's not a terminal no matter what I set it to.

I can use cgdb, but it does not seem to have an equivalent for layout reg. An alternative solution, is there any way to get gdb to work in TUI mode in windows?

Back to gdb. Per suggestion from @HolyBlackCat below, I tried CMD. The problem was that gdb is not in the path, and I didn't know how adding the path would affect windows. But I added:

```
PATH=c:\msys64\bin;c:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

It works, and gdb can run. layout src works but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
/etc/gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
Reading symbols from a...
```

Most important, at this point layout asm and reg work:

[image]

I still prefer using the bash shell that comes with msys2, so if there is any way to get gdb working under that it would be preferred.

Comment: Well, what is your terminal? Mintty? (aka MSYS2's default) CMD? Try CMD.

Comment: I tried msys2 (32 bit) msys2 (64 bit), and CMD. You gave me some ideas, and I will amend the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `winpty` at the very beginning of the `gdb` command that you run in MSYS2's MinTTY terminal.  So your command would start with `winpty gdb` and then have any arguments to `gdb`.

`winpty` is a handy utility that makes a lot of console things work better, and you can install it with `pacman -S winpty` if you don't have it yet.

Comment: never heard of it, but I tried it. gdb dies before the prompt. When I delete the commands layout asm from gdbinit, it does get to the prompt, but the moment I type the command it dies.