# Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal - GDB with GitBash

Tags: gdb, git-bash

I am using gitbash on windows and trying to debug a binary program however I am running into an issue with enabling TUI mode in gdb. I've previously used gdb with TUI enabled so I'm not sure what changed when. I compile my program `g++ -g -O0 -std=c++11 recursive_change.cpp -o recursive_change.o` and then run `gdb ./recursive-change.o`. From the gdb dialogue I am usually able to type `layout next` or `layout src` to get the graphical mode to show up however when I try this I get

```
Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal
```

Launching gdb with `--tui` gives the same error.

Program being compiled is itself very simple:

```cpp
int main() {
  int money = 0;
  int n_denominations = 0;
  std::vector<int> denominations; 

  std::cout << "enter money: ";
  std::cin >> money; 
  std::cout << "enter number of denominations: ";
  std::cin >> n_denominations;
}
```

Comment: Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250392/gdb-under-msys2-on-windows-11-cant-use-layout-not-a-terminal-is-there-a-termi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `winpty` before `gdb` solved the issue, as per suggestion by David Grayson here: [gdb under msys2 on windows 11 can't use layout "not a terminal" is there a terminal under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250392/gdb-under-msys2-on-windows-11-cant-use-layout-not-a-terminal-is-there-a-termi)